# При импорте sql таблицы в базу ошибка: "Unknown encoding or ..."

Tags: mysql

При импорте *sql*-таблицы в базу ошибка. Сервер новый, *VDS*.

> Warning: mb_strpos() [function.mb-strpos]: Unknown encoding or conversion error. in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/import/sql.php on line 152

Дампы маленькие, каждый от 90кб до 1.5мб. На любой из них одна и та же ошибка.

Как быть?

Comment: Unknown encoding or conversion error

ниочем не говорит?

Comment: Кодировки и прочее одинаковые. Базы идентичные, просто контент из одной в другую пытаюсь перенести.

Comment: Вышел из положения, восстановил дамп через ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятнее всего, *phpmyadmin* просто не может «справиться» с вашими данными.

можно попробовать воспользоваться программой `mysql`:

```
$ cat дамп.таблицы | mysql --user=пользователь --password=пароль база.данных
```